# How to recover the query data to use on a ListView using Access and VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm doing a query on Access and I want to recover the data of this query to put on a listview using `.EOF` and `.MoveNext`, but the `RecordCount` (the a variable) of my query is equal to -1. How can I do this?

```vb
Public Function ConsultaTabela_3(Optional ByVal planilha As String, Optional ByVal Consulta As String, Optional ByVal linha As String, Optional ByVal coluna As String, Optional ByVal prm1 As String, Optional ByVal prm2 As String, Optional ByVal prm3 As String, Optional ByVal prm4 As String, Optional ByVal prm5 As String, Optional ByVal prm6 As String)

Dim sSQL As String
Dim banco As ADODB.Connection
Dim tabela As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As ADODB.Command
Dim parametro1, parametro2, parametro3, parametro4, parametro5, parametro6 As ADODB.Parameter
'Dim caminhoDB As String
caminhoDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CALCULO_SLA.accdb"

On Error GoTo trataErro

'caminhoDB = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "MEDICAO_ALIMENTACAO.xlsm", "") & "MEDICAO_ALIMENTACAO.accdb"

Set banco = New ADODB.Connection
banco.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & caminhoDB & ";Persist Security Info=False"

' Abre a query ACCESS
Set query = New ADODB.Command
Set query.ActiveConnection = banco
query.CommandText = Consulta
query.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

' Pego o valor do param. e adiciono no command
Set parametro1 = query.CreateParameter("prm1", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro1
If prm1 = "" Then
    parametro1.Value = Null
Else
    parametro1.Value = prm1
End If

Set parametro2 = query.CreateParameter("prm2", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro2
If prm2 = "" Then
    parametro2.Value = Null
Else
    parametro2.Value = prm2
End If

Set parametro3 = query.CreateParameter("prm3", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro3
If prm3 = "" Then
    parametro3.Value = Null
Else
    parametro3.Value = prm3
End If

Set parametro4 = query.CreateParameter("prm4", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro4
If prm4 = "" Then
    parametro4.Value = Null
Else
    parametro4.Value = prm4
End If

Set parametro5 = query.CreateParameter("prm5", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro5
If prm5 = "" Then
    parametro5.Value = Null
Else
    parametro5.Value = prm5
End If

Set parametro6 = query.CreateParameter("prm6", adChar, adParamInput, 255)
query.Parameters.Append parametro6
If prm6 = "" Then
    parametro6.Value = Null
Else
    parametro6.Value = prm6
End If

' Executa a query no ACCESS
query.Execute

' Retorna a query para a tabela temporária e cola no excel
Set tabela = New ADODB.Recordset
tabela.Open query

a = tabela.RecordCount
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(planilha).Cells(CInt(linha), CInt(coluna)).CopyFromRecordset tabela

' Limpando memória
tabela.Close
Set tabela = Nothing
banco.Close
Set banco = Nothing

Exit Function

trataErro:
    MsgBox ("Erro: " & Err.Description)

End Function
```

Comment: Do you get the correct `tabela.RecordCount` if you insert  `tabela.CursorLocation=adUseClient` between `Set tabela = New ADODB.Recordset` and `tabela.Open`?

Comment: Perfect HansUp, it works just perfect! But can you please explain me what does this line mean? Because I didn't understande it! Thanks!

Comment: When experimenting with available options, I discovered `CursorLocation=adUseClient` could give me a valid `Recordset` in some situations where `Recordset` would report -1 without that `CursorLocation`.  But that's all I can say; I don't use ADO routinely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confirmed that using `adUseClient` for `CursorLocation` before opening the recordset gave you a valid `RecordCount` (instead of -1) ...

```vb
Set tabela = New ADODB.Recordset
tabela.CursorLocation=adUseClient '<-- this line added
tabela.Open query

a = tabela.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

The RecordCount property is often not available until you access all of the records.

Try:

```
 tabela.MoveLast
 tabela.MoveFirst
 a = tabela.RecordCount
```

Comment: It didn't works, return an error saying that "The bundle of lines do not offer support to regressive search"...